# Verify size of ldap backup file

Tags: ldap, devops

We have a job going on which takes the backup of ldap ( Using slapcat ). We are uploading the backup file (.ldif) to s3. We want to verify whether the backed up file is complete or incomplete, based on which it will push the data to s3.

I have tried counting out the lines of the file ( wc -l and find command ). But this will only count the lines, we want to cover the case where even number of lines is greater than 0, it should validate the backup. Basically, does ldap has any feature to validate the backup.

```
    - name: check whether file is empty or not, if yes, exit
      shell: "wc -l /tmp/ldap-backup.ldif|awk '{print $1}'"
      register: pl_checker
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't update earlier as I am not sure whether this is proper answer or just a hack.
What I did is an ldapsearch for objectClass=* and then used grep for objectClass and counted the line with wc -l. The value I got was compared with the value that I am getting by doing grep in the ldap backfile ( .ldif file ) and then counting number of lines in that. If both the number matches then number of objectClass matches and so the backup file has the complete data.
This was written in ansible playbook.

```
- name: Count number of objectClass by ldapsearch
  shell: "ldapsearch -LLL -xD'cn=<cn>,dc=ldap,dc=<env>,dc=<dc>,dc=<dc>' -w 
  <password> -b'dc=ldap,dc=<env>,dc=<dc>,dc=<dc>' objectClass=* | grep 
  objectClass | wc -l"
  register: pl_ldapsearch

- name: Count number of objectClass in backup (.ldif) file
  shell: "cat /tmp/ldap-backup.ldif | grep objectClass | wc -l"
  register: pl_ldapfile

- name: Delete backup file if it is incomplete
  file:
    path: /tmp/ldap-backup.ldif
    state: absent
    when: pl_ldapsearch.stdout != pl_ldapfile.stdout

- name: condition check
 fail: msg="ldap-backup.ldif file incomplete, intentionally failing the  
 playbook"
 when: pl_ldapsearch.stdout != pl_ldapfile.stdout
```

Not sure about the yml syntax as it changed while posting answer.